# Meaning of "redet sich im US-TV um Kopf und Kragen"

Tags: meaning, translation, german-to-english

This morning's Süddeutsche has a headline "Trump redet sich im US-TV um Kopf und Kragen".

I was looking for a good English translation, but pages likee [this](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/sich+um+kopf+und+kragen+reden.html) don't help. Can you?

Comment: In the case of this particular individual it might be sufficient to just write: "He's on TV."

Comment: Das ist ja eine Frage, die nach einem englischen Idiom sucht, also hier Fehl am Platze ist.

Comment: Someone upvoted  ` it might be sufficient to just write: "He's on TV."`??!! That loses the whole point of it

Comment: @Mawg  No, it just equates "T. speaks" with "T. risks his neck with careless talk". Which is, for this particular inidivdual, not a totally inappropriate equation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A translation of the term *sich um Kopf und Kragen reden* is

> to risk one's neck with careless talk

which seems to be a usual phrase in English.

Comment: I am wondering if one's neck is not meant personally, so to say I am digging the grave for someone else rather than for me?

Comment: @Thomas "**sich** um Kopf und Kragen reden" is reflexive, so it's one's personal neck.

Comment: @Annatar Right, the German "sich" is reflexive of course, but it is not in the English translation.

Comment: @Thomas Strictly speaking it's not, I guess. But I'd surely expect a "someone" instead of "one" if we speak about another person's neck, and assume that "one" is reflexive by default.

Comment: "To risk one's *own* neck with careless talk" would be less ambiguous, I guess.

Comment: What about *Trump risks **his** neck...* ;)

Comment: @Takkat, Cohen’s? :)

Comment: The best fitting English colloquialism seems to be "[he opened his mouth and put his foot in it](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-your-foot-in-your-mouth)"

Answer (score 6):

My favourite [dictionary](https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung?q=Kopf+und+Kragen&l=deen&in=de&lf=de) offers:

> to talk oneself into trouble

and yes, it is strongly addressing the talking person as afterwards in trouble. For other cases a different word like *denunzieren* would be used.